# Help To Solve a Simple Try Catch Block Error

Tags: c#

Im trying to use a try catch block But im facing some problems.. please help

this is the code and the error which Im getting is 
Error 1 The name 'Program' does not exist in the current context

```
using System;
namespace AddMinusDivideMultiply
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int i, j;

        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                Console.Write("Please Enter The First Number  :");
                string temp = Console.ReadLine();
                i = Int32.Parse(temp);

                Console.Write("Please Enter The Second Number :");
                temp = Console.ReadLine();
                j = Int32.Parse(temp);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" An Execption was thrown: {0}", e.Message);
            }

            Terms.Minus(); 
        }
        }
    }

    class Terms
    {
        public static void Add()
        {
            int add;
            add = Program.i + Program.j;
            Console.WriteLine("The Addition Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", add);
        }

        public static void Minus()
        {
        int minus;
        minus = Program.i - Program.j;
        Console.WriteLine("The Subraction Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", minus);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I copied it into Visual Studio. There is one closing bracket too much after Terms.Minus(). When I remove that, your program works fine here.

Comment: Originally there was no bracket in the end, I added it by accident when edited the code formatting first time. Brackets were the problem anyway =)

Comment: Clearly, the posted code does not match the actual code you're trying to run.  The Terms class is probably in a different source code file and is missing the namespace statement.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `AddMinusDivideMultiply.Program` instead. However strange, you are already in the correct namespace.

Comment: Either that, or put `Terms` in the `AddMinusDivideMultiply` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have a closing brace, making the Terms class outside of the AddMinusDivideMultiply namespace

Try this

```
using System;

namespace AddMinusDivideMultiply
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int i, j;

        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                Console.Write("Please Enter The First Number  :");
                string temp = Console.ReadLine();
                i = Int32.Parse(temp);

                Console.Write("Please Enter The Second Number :");
                temp = Console.ReadLine();
                j = Int32.Parse(temp);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" An Execption was thrown: {0}", e.Message);
            }

            Terms.Minus(); 
        }
    }


    class Terms
    {
        public static void Add()
        {
            int add;
            add = Program.i + Program.j;
            Console.WriteLine("The Addition Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", add);
        }

        public static void Minus()
        {
        int minus;
        minus = Program.i - Program.j;
        Console.WriteLine("The Subraction Of The First and The Second Number is {0}", minus);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your braces are not balanced, there are two braces closing the Main method where you want one.